# An error has occurred when I use the Bayes Net Toolbox for MATLAB to implement Gibbs Sampling

Tags: matlab, sampling, bayesian-networks

It warns the function `compute_posterior` is undefined, and I found the file `compute_posterior.c` in my toolbox.

Why it is not the `.m` file? How to solve the problem?

```
Undefined function 'compute_posterior' for input arguments of type 'struct'.

Error in gibbs_sampling_inf_engine/marginal_nodes (line 101)
  post = compute_posterior (bnet, state, m, engine.strides, engine.families, ...

Error in gibbs_test1 (line 26)
[mg ge] = marginal_nodes (ge,[1,2]);"
```